# Horizontal QListWidget

Tags: qt-creator

How can I make Horizontal QListWidget?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`flow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#flow-prop) property to choose if the items will be laid out vertically or horizontally.

Comment: setFlow(QListWidget::LeftToRight);
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [isWrapping](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlistview.html#isWrapping-prop) property. Set it to true.

Comment: This will not display the items horizontally but wrap them when the widget border is reached